# How to identify the number of nodes and their voltage in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image]

Voltage at each node is required considering the bottom wire is connected to ground, thus making the voltage zero at the bottom everywhere. 
Is following nodes correct?

[image]

Comment: You might want to include your train of thought to receive better feedback. The more specific the question the better.

Comment: Wait, why does the voltage at the bottom have to be zero?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct.

A node encompasses all the places in the circuit that are connected together by ideal wires.

So the two dots you indicated along the bottom edge are both part of the same node.

And you missed two other nodes in the circuit that aren't connected to that node or to the nodes you labeled as V1 and V2.